# How to parse complex data using react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Following is the DATA that needs to parse which can nested arrays and objects i need
help understanding the easiest way to parse this .

```
const country= [
   {   
      "place": "sikkim",
      "location": 2,
      "Extension": "",
      "Keys": {
        "string": [
          "Enabled",
          "Disabled"
        ]
      },
      "ItemValues": {  
        "ItemData": [
          {
            "Name": "Enabled",
            "Data": {
              
              "Rows": {
               
                "Row": {
      
                  "Values": {
       
                    "Type": false
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "Name": "Value",
            "Data": {
             
              "Rows": {
                "DataRow": {
                  "Values": {
                    "anyType": "100"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "place": "assam",
      "location": 1,
      "Extension": "",
      "Keys": {
        "string": "MinValue"
      },
      "ItemValues": {
        "ItemData": {
          "Name": "nValue",
          "Data": {
            
            "Rows": {
              "DataRow": {
                "Values": {
                  "anyType": "1"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      
    }
    }
]
```

In this array 2 objects are there i need to parse this complex array of object and
show like this -

```
 OUTCOME should be -

sikkim:{ 
  "place": "sikkim",
  "location": 2,
  "Extension": "",
  "string":"Enabled","Disabled",
  "Name": "Enabled",
   "Type": false,
   "Name": "Value",
   "anyType": 100
},
assam:{.. so on}

code that i tried is displaying only keys -
 

  const getValues = country =>
  country === Object(country)
  ? Object.values(country).flatMap(getValues)
  : [country];
  console.log(getValues(country));
 
  OUTPUT from above code = 

   ["sikkim", 2, "", "Enabled", "Disabled", "Enabled", false, "Value", "100", 
    "assam", 1, "", "MinValue", "nValue", "1"]
```

Need to write logic which is smart way to write to cover this logic because my data
is huge any leads?I can achieve the output but writing many for and if loops but that
creates lot of confusion.

Comment: Your expected output isn't a valid object. You can't have two values for the same key.

Comment: Ohk ignore that "string":"Disabled" then is there any way to achieve?